# Does JVM has its runtime branch prediction? If so, is there a way in Java code to hint branch results?

Tags: java, jvm

As the title says:

I remember that in some C compilers (such as GCC), we're able to give hint to compiler about likely branch prediction results. Does JVM have such function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless there's some new annotation that's escaped me, no.

On the other hand, it's not clear how terribly useful such a feature would be. Remember that, unlike a language such as C/C++, "prediction" at the level of the source code isn't necessarily the best strategy because What The Code Is Actually Doing In Practice as it is running isn't a mystery: the JVM can potentially monitor critical behaviour and if necessary re-compile sections of code in accordance with its measurements.

Comment: To reinforce Neil's answer: most modern JVMs most certainly do monitor branch behaviours and try to get the branches set up the right way for CPUs to predict more easily.

Answer (score 1):

No, the JVM has no such compiler hints or optimizations at the source level.

Comment: I agree about hints, as they would have to be in the source language, and they aren't. However the HotSpot JVM is one big optimizer and it behaves according to gathered statistics on execution behaviour, so I don't know how you can be so dogmatic as to say there is no such optimization. On the other hand the question is rather incorrectly formed. It is the *CPU* that has branch prediction: all a compiler can do is order the code such that it works best with the CPU.

Comment: @EJP - of course i wasn't referring to what happened inside the jvm, i meant at the source level.

Answer (score 1):

This post is interesting and includes a case where Java branch prediction fails:

[Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)